# Who should handle animations when game logic is separated from rendering?

Tags: animation, rendering, scrolling

Suppose I have a tile-based game and I want the step to be 1 tile but also want the movement to be smooth while the player is getting there. If I understand correctly, the only way to achieve this would be making a series of small movements where the increment is a percentage of a tile.

My question is: should the game logic thread send the animations to the rendering thread? What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: This almost begs the question to me of why there even needs to exist separate rendering and logic threads at all in a game that is tile-based. This is a huge amount of added complexity to keep track of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep rendering perfectly separate from the game logic, animations - at least the ones that have no game logic impact - are solely done from the "rendering" side. A common pattern is to record the transition using three bits of data:

- Start value
- End value
- Time (between 0 and 1)

The advantage of this approach is that it can be easily fed into an [easing function](http://easings.net/) so you can choose a style that suits.

To use this pattern, you detect whenever the player has moved from one tile to another. The **start value** will be the position of **the previous tile**, the **end value** will 
be that of **the current tile**, but to figure out **time** you need to record **when the player began moving**, and compare that against the **current game time**.

That's not the only method though; a simpler method would be to track the **player's position** in the "rendering" side, and **constantly move** this position **towards the "game logic"'s position**.

But finally, don't be so concerned about having the perfect design, especially when making games; if it's easier to hold some "rendering" data in the "game logic", just do it - you can clean it up later if it's hampering things.